# How can I have /var/log/messages use the FQDN instead of the short hostname?

Tags: syslog

I've noticed even when I type "hostname" at the CLI the FQDN is displayed, however the only file that seems to be using the short name is /var/log/messages.  I'd prefer it to use the FQDN however I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

syslog-ng supports the following option :

use-fqdn(yes);

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in your **/etc/hostname** ??

Try changing it and run

```
hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

Additionally you can try adding only a FQHN reference in your **/etc/hosts**:

```
YOURIP      your_host.yourdomain.tld
```